# Генерация сочетаний на основе данных из DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, комбинаторика

Как сгенерировать сочетания без повторений (по 2 элемента из 4) для каждой строки DataFrame и результат сохранить в единый список?
Привел код, который частично работает. Непонятно как сгенерированные сочетаний перевести в единный массив (уникальных записей) и сделать это быстро. Кол-во записей порядка 2 миллионов.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import itertools as itr 


df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
print(df)

ndf = df.apply(lambda x: list(itr.combinations(x,2)), axis = 1)
print(list(ndf.values))
```

Исходные данные:

```
   0   1   2   3
0  1   2   3   4
1  5   6   7   8
2  9  10  11  12
```

Промежуточные данные полученные с помощью кода:

```
[[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)], [(5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8)], [(9, 10), (9, 11), (9, 12), (10, 11), (10, 12), (11, 12)]]
```

Желаемый результат:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8), (9, 10), (9, 11), (9, 12), (10, 11), (10, 12), (11, 12)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = []
B = ndf.values.tolist()

for i in B:
  A.extend(i)

#без for
sum(ndf, [])
```

Comment: а без for возможно?

Comment: Спасибо. Красивое решение.